# Magento 2.4.3-p3 Insert Image in CMS page - Media structure tree doesn't load

Tags: magento2

We have a strange issue with adding an image to a CMS page.
When we click 'insert image' in the content of the CMS page, the 'Insert File' flyout doesn't load the Media Folders Structure.
We just see the whirling icon as it tries to load the folder structure.
It just hangs there.
I've tested the new media gallery by changing the 'Enable Old Media Gallery' to NO and this seems to work fine.
However, we prefer to use the old gallery system.
Please see image to demonstrate what we see.
What could be the problem here please?

Andy

[image: HERE]

Comment: It could be something related to permission issues.. Kindly check in the console tab is there any error while loading page ?

Answer (score 0):

It could be due to a bug or compatibility issue with your CMS version. Try upgrading your CMS to the latest version or contact the CMS support team for assistance.

Answer (score 0):

we do see some errors but we see the same in a copy of the site which has been upgraded to 2.4.5-p1

```
/cms/page/edit/page_id/48/key/4245e8e1973c0db88dc5e8a0c1139a4092944195a1491220b56ebdacf6d84ec8/:1 The Content-Security-Policy directive 'frame-ancestors' does not support the source expression ''unsafe-inline'' jquery-migrate.js:23 JQMIGRATE: Migrate is installed with logging active, version 1.4.1 DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for http://mysite.co.uk.co.uk/static/version1677775733/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_GB/Magento_PageBuilder/js/stage-builder.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_FAILURE DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for http://mysite.co.uk.co.uk/static/version1677775733/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_GB/Magento_PageBuilder/js/content-type-collection.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_FAILURE DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for http://mysite.co.uk.co.uk/static/version1677775733/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_GB/Magento_PageBuilder/js/content-type-factory.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_FAILURE DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for http://mysite.co.uk.co.uk/static/version1677775733/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_GB/Magento_PageBuilder js/config.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_FAILURE
```

Hi Harun
Do you mean to Magento 2 version or the CMS module?

Thank you
Andy

Answer (score 0):

Update:
I've noticed that in Firefox 'web developer tools' the media root tree loops the loading json file continiously and when copying the file link I see this.

```
http://mywebsite.co.uk/myadmin/cms/wysiwyg_images/treeJson/current_tree_path/d3lzaXd5Zw--/key/16b7a63a4c373b19b1416cd1f5d70a775fa03d21333c79675698d9519fc4d47c/?isAjax=true
```

When clicking this link (please note that I have masked our website url) I see this.

```
'"/var/www/vhosts/mysite.co.uk/htdocs/public_html/pub/media/htaccess" is not a valid file path'
```

Hope it helps you to help me.
Thank you
Andy